# Can "however" and "meanwhile" be used in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: conjunctions

Is it acceptable to have the joining words *meanwhile* and *however* in the middle of a sentence? I have always thought that they should open a sentence, unlike other conjunctions such as *because* or *although* which can used at the beginning of a sentence or in the middle.

Comment: One would normally expect to find _however_ at the start of the sentence; however, it could also be used like this.

Answer (score 11):

If they are inside parenthetical commas, yes.

> "The boss, however, didn't agree."
>   "The enemy, meanwhile, continued
>   to advance."

Comment: I like both examples. (I took the liberty, however, of putting them in a quote box; I hope you don't mind.)  Your answer, meanwhile, continues to get upvoted. +1

Answer (score 7):

These words can be used within **parathetical commas** (as pointed out by Roaring Fish +1) *or* as a conjunctive adverb **following a semicolon**.  When used with a semicolon they begin an independent phrase which is linked using the word.  For example:

> *It can occur in both melodic and harmonic lines; however, it is subject to certain restraints.* [*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon)

While the second independent phrase could stand on its own as a sentence, there may be reasons why one might choose to conjoin the two phrases using a semicolon and the [conjunctive adverb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_adverb).